# how to ping two vlan forwarding in a network

Tags: vlan

[image]

hello , i have a question ! how can i connect two pc
in different vlan connection together.it must be refer to **loopback test** and **virtual interface**. and which techology can i solve this ploblem!THX

i have try set make pc1 port bind to vlan10 and pc2 port bind to vlan20 , and put them to sw1's interface g1/0/2 and sw2's interface g1/0/2.last make sw1's interface g1/0/1 and sw2's interface g1/0/1 connect use a netline and configure two interface to trunk mode.but havn't konw the answer.THX!

Comment: One of your switches must be l3 capable, it is not, you can not be able to ping from one pc located on "vlan x" , to another located on "vlan y"

Comment: yes,both switch support L3,and how can i configure,THX

Comment: Can you put your model devices??

Comment: sorry ! in our country we use H3C device , can you give me an example device to solve this ploblem . THX

Comment: and my leader told me to use loopback to test and want me to refer to vlan-interface.are they useful to this ploblem?

Comment: Yes, i put some way to do that, with loopback interfaces, called also vlan interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get sw1 and sw2 and define 2 vlans, vlan10 and vlan20.
2. Enable ip routing on your L3 switches.
3. Create on one of they, eg, sw1
   2 vlan interfaces and set on it, his respective ip address:

interface vlan 10
ip address x.x.10.x 255.255.255.0

interface vlan 20
ip address x.x.20.x 255.255.255.0

3. On pc connected to vlan 10 access port, declare it gateway like x.x.10.x, and on pc on vlan20 port, x.x.20.x
4. Declare link between sw1 and sw2 link trunk port.

With this, your vlan communication will work

Comment: thank you for your answer ! and i will test on workdays if have any other ploblems i will consult you!

Comment: No problem, i hope you can solve with this

Answer (score -1):

Typically you don't set VLAN id on the PC/endpoint.  The VLAN is set by the network equipment (switch).  You will need a router (sometimes also called a layer 3 switch) in order to route between the VLAN's.

There is something called inter-VLAN bridging where you essentially put both VLAN's in a configuration where each sees the others frames.  In this case, the secondary-address would enable you to talk to the other VLAN, provided each VLAN had a corresponding IP subnet associated with it.

Comment: VLAN 10 and 20 are *layer-2 isolated*. It doesn't matter how many secondary address one adds to the *vlan 10* layer-3 interface, nothing in vlan 20 will be able to talk to it.

Comment: VLAN10 does talk IP to VLAN20.  The corresponding subnets would normally talk via their default gateway (the int VLAN).  The secondary ip address is in case they are on a flat network with separated VLANs.  Maybe I misunderstood the diagram.

Comment: Only if there's a router in there, which there isn't -- or wasn't included in the diagram or question. (which, btw, *is* his entire question.)